# mysql select grouping by maximum and get unique row

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this data on MySql table:

```
unit_code                                   |       amount  |       effective_from
52599244-6a7f-408b-a1fc-41278a31af59        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
167e3920-daf0-4f24-ab61-d5efb22a37d0        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
ca8efdeb-817f-4ab9-a959-edef8663bcfa        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
463d5cd5-b30a-46a5-ae7e-95f6f6924edf        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
346264ad-4fa3-48d6-b3ca-830a0ff9a1e6        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
80c2fa42-be9e-4550-a377-04cd63468ba9        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
b2153987-2bff-4c91-9777-16a2f920b990        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
6c9769d9-6478-4698-a777-99d6141ade34        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
b57fcf7e-1403-4fcc-a2f6-70b235b7eea1        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
a67362ef-ff05-45bf-94f8-725d0cf030da        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
288ea5cf-8e1c-4d26-b891-b59579119853        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
3b0f137b-b965-450a-a729-70b50286fa43        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
c9f14429-92dc-4698-853d-7f8831bd30dd        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
be15e011-221b-45e1-a493-df5959546a54        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
8701bdeb-6948-405f-81c3-6958c1e6f727        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
68e4fd8e-6fc1-431d-9b75-0c9766129aa5        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
776b706d-bc19-416e-8b9c-e479b55d3be2        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
7ac72a15-7028-41c3-879b-a478198dd8be        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
06e93241-d08a-4f43-87a9-ceae07e05c80        |       4500        |       3/1/2021
09e46ea7-d0de-4c64-aa9c-a2886a5e7211        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
495c7790-a248-49db-90b6-1be1814f52c8        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
71fa2c19-6149-4e20-8562-9186da99ac68        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
08cb1844-0c38-4f76-8aed-9a5b2d4c0519        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
898a9228-8d70-4a4a-8330-6e68dfef96f7        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
1c12922b-48a2-4aea-8d3f-3c8a881ad835        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
7f6fbc36-9749-422c-8f58-6dd49171fde4        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
523a10ce-f334-45b0-a1cd-58ac57de80f7        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
167e3920-daf0-4f24-ab61-d5efb22a37d0        |       6700        |       7/1/2021
167e3920-daf0-4f24-ab61-d5efb22a37d0        |       11996       |       7/1/2021
167e3920-daf0-4f24-ab61-d5efb22a37d0        |       6800        |       8/1/2021
95363e75-7ee6-4202-b7b1-5f681d560355        |       10000       |       28/1/2021
cf8fe894-18d6-47ec-ad3e-84828003455e        |       10000       |       28/1/2021
1c684a35-812b-4107-8c3e-27859293f6d6        |       10000       |       28/6/2021
50c42b42-c889-41c0-a572-8075f1341ad1        |       10000       |       28/1/2021
35a9d086-1dec-4151-a8ab-21610a8752af        |       10000       |       28/1/2021
ebb6ab8b-d933-4ee6-966b-968155def517        |       10000       |       28/1/2021
a7d10c49-420d-4c75-a2c1-f48cc4fb159e        |       6000        |       25/2/2021
405272f0-a100-476a-8263-5856e090b561        |       12000       |       8/3/2021
ebe9571d-f7df-4dc8-bc50-230eac24dd6a        |       12000       |       8/3/2021
4f52d59a-090d-4a5c-ba39-d4352be57336        |       12000       |       8/3/2021
1d81b529-fb5f-42cd-b624-c1547614337f        |       12000       |       7/3/2021
1d81b529-fb5f-42cd-b624-c1547614337f        |       6788        |       9/3/2021
346264ad-4fa3-48d6-b3ca-830a0ff9a1e6        |       888         |       9/1/2021
06e93241-d08a-4f43-87a9-ceae07e05c80        |       669         |       13/3/2021
```

I want to select unique unit_code(unit_code can have several occurances in the table, in the unit_code column), the amount and date where date is maximum and date is equal or less than today.
Am trying but am not getting even near the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the rows you want. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by unit_code
                      order by effective_from desc) as rn
  from t
  where effective_from <= curdate()
) x
where rn = 1
```